# Using Maclaurin series with solving a multi-variable limits

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I need to determine wheter there's a limit where $(x,y)=(0,0)$ of the next function:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^{x(y+1)}-x-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

In order to simplify the expression can I use maclaurin series on $e^{x(y+1)}?$ If so it's equal to $e^{x(y+1)}=1+x(y+1)+o(x(y+1))$ and putting it on the expression will simplify it to:$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy+o(x(y+1))}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and using polar I can prove the limit is equal to $0$.

Is the above correct? Can I use maclaurin series?

Comment: Your approach is correct and nice (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $xy + o(x(y+1)) = xy + o(xy) + o(x) = o(x)$ so it suffices to show $\frac{o(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to 0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. This is immediate since $|x| = \sqrt{x^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. (That is, $o(x) \subseteq o(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.)

Comment: I'm missing the reason why $xy+o(xy)+o(x)=o(x)$.

Comment: Can you explain that?

Comment: $xy/x = y \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, $o(xy)/x = o(y) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, and the sum of elements of $o(x)$ is also $o(x)$.

Comment: I guess I should also mention that the notation $f(x) = o(x)$ is a dangerous abuse of notation since, for instance $x^3 = o(x^2)$ and $x^3 = o(x)$ but $o(x) \neq o(x^2)$. We should really write $f(x) \in o(x)$ when there is any ambiguity.